# FreshMVVM and resetting VM before popping Modal

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

- FreshMVVM 3.0.0
- Xamarin Forms 4.2

A number of our input pages are loaded modally and when the user presses Save we execute a `Command` like this

```
var newTemperature = new Temperature()
{
    Date = DateTime.Now,
    Value = this.TemperatureValue,
    CaptureType = CaptureType.Manual,
    IsModified = true,
};

await this.Services.DataService.SaveAsync(newTemperature);

// Save completed, now close modal.
await this.CoreMethods.PopPageModel(data, modal, animate);
```

If you look at the [`CoreMethods.PopPageModel` call in GitHub](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/blob/e06a84e79a41fdea801fec9e6f32a82dbdad544c/src/FreshMvvm/PageModelCoreMethods.cs) you can see that it deals with two processes

1. Raising the PageWasPopped signal
2. Calling to the Navigation Service to pop the page off of the navigation stack

The `FreshMVVM` code that [handles the page being popped is in FreshPageModel](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/blob/d197cbeaa96fc2712f37433570297086816f9c66/src/FreshMvvm/FreshBasePageModel.cs#L137). Among other things the code unhooks from the Appearing and Disappearing events and **sets the BindingContext to null**. As you can see from the above order that means the `BindingContext` on the `View` is set to null before it is popped off the stack.

The problem with this is that for a short period of between 0.5 and 1.5 seconds the user sees a `View` that looks like the data has all been reset. This could be quite disconcerting if they have just pressed Save.

If I reverse the order of the logic in `PopPageModel` and pop from the navigation stack before calling `RaisePageWasPopped` this issue goes away.

Has nobody else seen this problem before?

Any users of `FreshMVVM` who want to point out the error of my suggested approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our solution to this issue was to implement our own PopPageModel method which essentially switches the order around so that PopPage is called on the Navigation Stack before a call to `RaisePageWasPopped`

This is what we call when we want to dismiss the Page

```
public Task DismissAsync(bool modal = true, bool animate = true)
{
    return this.DispatcherService.RunOnUiThreadAsync(
        async () =>
            {
                string navServiceName = this.CurrentNavigationServiceName;
                if (this.IsModalFirstChild)
                {
                    await this.CoreMethods.PopModalNavigationService(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    IFreshNavigationService rootNavigation = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IFreshNavigationService>(navServiceName);
                    await rootNavigation.PopPage(modal, animate);

                    if (modal)
                    {
                        this.RaisePageWasPopped();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just note that the service is being awaited, holding the UI until service completes, 
have you tried removing `await` and popping the page immediately or displaying a loader while the service is busy?

`this.InsertReports(metadata.Reports).ConfigureAwait(false);`